# ssh connect to remote machine under 4g

Tags: ssh

I could ssh remote connect to my home computer under different wifi

[image: wifi connect]

but fail to connect under 4g,

ping works properly.
[image]

Comment: In case it matters, you haven't blurred out the full IP address in the 2nd screenshot.  Does your ssh server config restrict connections from particular IP addresses?

Comment: ty. No, it's my home computer. @JeffSchaller

Comment: A connection is being established but it then gets terminated. Check the logs of your home computer (typically `/var/log/secure`, `/var/log/auth.log` or similar): the `sshd` daemon should have logged a clear message describing the reason why it terminated the connection.